# Argument is out of range

Tags: c#, .net, string, substring

I have a variable, that got alot of content that I need to sort through.
But using IndexOf and Substring, just gives me an error that ain't that much obvious.

> ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Argument is out of range.
>
> Parameter name: startIndex

The error is happening on the "string lookThroughString = .." line.

My code is simply trying to look through a string, find the correct content and then spit it out.

```
private string SCRIPT_CONTENT;

public string GetVariable(string variable_name) {
    int length = 0;
    string lookThroughString = SCRIPT_CONTENT.Substring(SCRIPT_CONTENT.IndexOf(variable_name));

    foreach(char c in lookThroughString) {
        if(c.ToString() != ";") {
            length++;
        }
    }
    return SCRIPT_CONTENT.Substring(SCRIPT_CONTENT.IndexOf(variable_name + "::"), length);
}
```

The "Script" / "Content" i'm looking through is:

```
spellName::Fireball;
spellID::1;
```

I want this function, to return basicly from the start of the entered variable name (In this case 'SpellName') and until the first semicolon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that your `variable_name` variable value is `"SpellName"` but the value in your string is actually `"spellName"` (with a lowercase `s`). Since that variable name can't actually be found in the string, `.IndexOf(variable_name)` returns -1, and `.Substring` can't take a negative index as a parameter.

A quick solution is to simply check the result of `IndexOf` before you use it:

```
int index = SCRIPT_CONTENT.IndexOf(variable_name);
if (index < 0) {
    return string.Empty; // or throw an exception
}

string lookThroughString = SCRIPT_CONTENT.Substring(index);
```

But we can simplify this method to:

```
public string GetVariable(string variable_name) {
    int startIndex = SCRIPT_CONTENT.IndexOf(variable_name);
    if (startIndex < 0) {
        return string.Empty; // or throw an exception
    }

    startIndex += variable_name.Length + 2;
    int endIndex = SCRIPT_CONTENT.IndexOf(";", startIndex);
    return SCRIPT_CONTENT.Substring(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex);
}
```

Or if you're open to using [regular expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), you can simplify it even more:

```
public string GetVariable(string variable_name) {
    var pattern = string.Format("{0}::(.*?);", Regex.Escape(variable_name));
    return Regex.Match(SCRIPT_CONTENT, pattern).Groups[1].ToString();
}
```

Comment: Didn't solve the problem quite. It returns everything in the "Script", instead of only the "SpellName" line.

Comment: @KevinJensenPetersen What exactly do you want it to return? Just `"Fireball"` or the entire line?

Comment: Actually only the "Fireball" word, since that is what SpellName variable contains. But I was trying to start with getting the line first.

Comment: I see.. That's actually pretty simple, I don't know why I didn't think of that. I thank you so much! You have saved me for alot of frustrations trying to solve the problem.